# How to enable proxy users (personal representatives) to access the mail account - the right way

Tags: java, authentication, jakarta-mail

What I am trying to do is accessing an e-mail server (Apache James - trunk-version, in my case) from a Java application. This works well with an LDAP configured for the authentication.

However, I have a problem here that consists of two things. 
First, I have to store the password in the user session to authenticate against the mail server (I don't want any password floating around in my code - not even encrypted or temporary)
Second, I also want to enable the user to define another user to access his inbox. Of course that user doesn't contain the right password.

For the first one (except for one master password), I haven't found a good alternative yet. For the second one, I was looking into SASL, but wasn't able to find any good documentation or sample configurations at all, that illustrate such a set-up.

I might be naive, but I thought such a scenario is more or less common case, but wasn't able to find a satisfying answer. Any help, might it be documentation pointers, other concepts/ specs/ ideas, would be greatly appreciated. Especially the second point point is bugging me.

Answer (score 0):

We then check if the credentials are valid. If they are valid, we would send an user object back to the client along with an access token.This token has an expiration time associated with it. And the client is expected to send this token to the server everytime a request is made to read the mail box. This is our custom way of authenticating a client.

You can use JWT or OAUTH for generating a token.